# The argument 'UploadParallelActiveTasks' is larger than maximum of '64'

Tags: azure, blob

It seems that the above error occurs when I am trying to upload a large file to Azure blob storage.

Here is what i had while declaring the `CloudBlobClient`.

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
blobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 1;
blobClient.SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 67108864;
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(fileByte, 0, fileByte.Count());
```

However why is it that when I had already set the `ParallelOperationThreadCount` to 1 and yet this exception occurs?

Edited: Added the stacktrace below.

```
The argument 'UploadParallelActiveTasks' is larger than maximum of '64'  Parameter name: UploadParallelActiveTasks<InnerException><trace source>
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertInBounds[T](String paramName, T val, T min, T max)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.set_ParallelOperationThreadCount(Int32 value)
   at App1.App.<uploadImageToBlobStorage>d__3b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at App1.WallpaperPage.<>c__DisplayClass3.<<btnAcceptPreview_Click>b__1>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
```

Comment: Which exact line is giving the exception? I believe that code will give a clue.

Comment: What's the blob size you're trying to upload?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson am unable to identify from the error log which exact line is giving exception.

Comment: @GauravMantri most like ~50MB?

Comment: @LZH Is there any way to run it in the debugger and just break on the exception? Looks like `ParallelOperationThreadCount` is changed to a value above 64 by something, since the setter is the one throwing the exception.

Comment: What surprises me is that the exception contains `UploadParallelActiveTasks`. It should have been `ParallelOperationThreadCount`. I looked up for this string in the source code but couldn't find it. Which version of storage client library are you using?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i wasn't able to reproduce the exception on my end.

Comment: @GauravMantri i am using 3.0.1.0, previously when i didn't set blobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 1, the exception was ParallelOperationThreadCount. I found the UploadParallelActiveTasks at https://github.com/richorama/azure-sdk-for-mono/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/StorageClient/CloudBlobClient.cs